# Qt: QHostAddress: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm new to Qt and when I try to run a program I get import error

```
fatal error: QHostAddress: No such file or directory
```

Caused by the import in main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QHostAddress>
```

It seems that there is missing of QHostAddress.h while QCoreApplication.h is  available

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you have something to the effect of :

```
QT += network
```

In your .pro file. Then run qmake again, and recompile.